# 'scale' and 'svg' does not exist in "node_modules/@types/d3/index"

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph using Angular 2 and D3 JS, below are NPM packages I added:

```
"d3": "4.4.0",
"d3-tip": "0.7.1",
"@types/d3": "^4.3.0",
```

Below typescript file gave error while compiling:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-bar-chart',
  template: require('./about.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./about.component.css').toString()]
})

export class AboutComponent {
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x0)
        .orient("bottom");
```

Errors are:

```
ERROR in ./angular2App/app/components/about/about.component.ts
(34,21): error TS2339: Property 'scale' does not exist on type 'typeof "App_path/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'.

ERROR in ./angular2App/app/components/about/about.component.ts
(44,24): error TS2339: Property 'svg' does not exist on type 'typeof "App_path/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code uses D3 **v3** whereas you configured a library version **v4.4.0**. Since v4 is now modular all namespaces needed to be [flattened](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40):

> However, there is one unavoidable consequence of adopting ES6 modules: every symbol in D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x.

More specifically:

1. The linear scale is included in module [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md) (see [changes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale)):

   - d3.scale.linear ↦ [d3.scaleLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleLinear)
2. Axes belong to module [d3-axis](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#axes-d3-axis).

   - d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom") ↦ [d3.axisBottom(scale)](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axisBottom)

Comment: So this would be the same right? D3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale) = D3.axisBottom(this.xScale); There's no orient so I'm assuming x is bottom. Hope I'm not way off here...

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai Yes, these should produce roughly the same output, although it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code. If it's not clear yet or you are facing any issues, please post that as a full-fledged question instead.

Comment: Just an FYI that I tried it and it worked on the first try. Thanks again!