# cant access like `d3.svg(), d3.scale()` and some others properties in d3js with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.js in angular2
Iam using the below command to install d3 in Angular2

```
npm install --save d3
install --save-dev @types/d3
```

my **package.json** look like

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

and i add path to .angular-cli.json

some of the properties i cant access like `d3.svg(), d3.scale()` and some others

It returns error.

what could be the reason?

Comment: You shouldn't have to update `.angular-cli.json` file. I have a working [github](https://github.com/PdUi/ng-d3v4-components/tree/ng-bubble-latest) repo, showing how to use d3 in angular. It is very hard to answer your question here because it isn't clear what is going wrong and what you have tried. Where are you trying to use those functions(include the code) and what is the error exactly you are getting? Also, when are you getting the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['scale' and 'svg' does not exist in "node\_modules/@types/d3/index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988732/scale-and-svg-does-not-exist-in-node-modules-types-d3-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the specific method from d3, the same way rxjs operators.

```
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';
```

You can use the method without the d3 namespace as:

```
var x = scaleLinear();
```

Alternatively, you can import all

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

var x = d3.scaleLinear();
```

Note that there is no scale in d3.v4